# How does Magic Find work in Guild Wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

There are many items which grant increased magic find (+X% Magic Find), and I'm curious exactly how it works, since it varies from game to game. In some games Magic Find just results in more items dropping, and in others it results in a higher chance for rarer items to drop.

How does Magic Find work in Guild Wars 2?

Comment: Related question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/82623/16007

Comment: According to the wiki, it says a chance of rarer loot to drop - that implies to me that you'll get rarer items but not more items.

I'd really like a better answer, though.  I've been wondering this myself - also, does this !@#! finding crafting materials?  Personal experience seems to give me more maces/swords/foci when I have +mf% than small claws/small scales/etc.

Comment: @esnyder considering crafting materials are blue texted and higher, it would definitely not screw up material farming.

Comment: @Jay That's what I thought, too.  It seems there's a "sweet spot" in magic find for crafting materials, as I mentioned I often get more swords/shields/foci than materials with heavy +mf%.  Not sure what it is, though....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The Guild Wars 2 wiki states](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Magic_find) that Magic find is an attribute which increases a players *chance* to receive rare loot from drops, which would indicate that the quality of the drops increases, rather than the number of drops. [This forum thread](http://www.guildwars2guru.com/topic/64171-full-magic-find-gear-worth-it/) on Guild Wars 2 Guru again indicates that it is the quality of the items that increases, rather than the number of drops.

In addition to increasing the quality of drops, it will also effect getting crafting materials.

The current common belief is that all of your bonuses to magic find are additive and is used as a modifier value. So for example, if you have two bonuses of 50% magic find, you will end up with 100% total magic find.

If a mob had a 5% to drop a ‘fine’ quality crafting ingredient or piece of equipment that chance would be increased by the value of your magic find (100%) to 10%.

The easiest and cheapest way is to buy/make magic find food, but it is also possible to get magic find items, upgrades, and runes.

Good food to eat in order to increase your magic find is the [Omnomberry Bar](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Omnomberry_Bar) or Chocolate Omnomberry Cream. Chocolate Omnomberry Cream provides a 40% magic find bonus but for farming in general it would be better to use Omnomberry Bars as this also provides a +Gold find bonus, in addition to some experience.

Comment: [Worth noting that Magic Find % doesn't apply to opening chests.](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/game/dungeons/Magic-Find-Chests/first#post597487)

Comment: Since MF is now account wide, I've heard that it only takes effect in WvW. Is that true? It's useless in PvE now?

Answer (score -2):

Quick point regarding percentage chance:

"The current common belief is that all of your bonuses to magic find are additive and is used as a modifier value. So for example, if you have two bonuses of 50% magic find, you will end up with 100% total magic find."

I would think that rather than giving you 100% chance, it would INCREASE your chance by 100%. So if ingame mechanics (without your bonus) say says you have a 1% chance to get a rarer item, then you get a BONUS chance of 100%. 100% increase on your 1% is 2%. If you started with a 40% chance, then you'd end up with 80% chance.

At least that's how it works in my head. Thoughts?

Comment: Downvoted because the answer is practically identical to the one posted by pixel.

Comment: @jay And now the answer posted by pixel is gone (unless they changed their name to kalina).