# Is the consumable magic find buff multiplative or additive?

Tags: guild-wars-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Magic Find work in Guild Wars 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82609/how-does-magic-find-work-in-guild-wars-2)

Currently my armor, weapon, and accessory is set up to maximize magic find. my gear is as follows:

- +18% magic find from having 6 explorer armor pieces.
- +60% magic find from having 5 pieces of Superior Rune of the Pirate and 1 piece of Superior Rune of the Explorer.
- 12% from two single handed explorer weapons that both have Opal gems
- 9% from 3 opal gems on my accessories.

Combined that is 99% magic find. Now I introduce in another magic find factor, Food consumable. I am currently using Cherry tart which says:

> Nourishment: 18% Magic Find, +40 Power +10 Exp. from kills.

Is this consumable multiplicatively increasing my magic find since it doesn't say 18% magic find without the addition sign? If that is the case then I rather not waste using the consumable since it will add negligible difference.

If it is additive, what happens when you have over 100% magic find?

Comment: Re your last question, you may be committing the same fallacy that a lot of D3 players did. 100% magic find doesn't necessarily mean you will find an item 100% of the time, it simply means that you have 100% *better* chance to find an item. ie. if you normally have a 10% chance to find a magic item, you now how have a 20% chance to find one. We probably won't know this till there's an answer to this question though: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82609/how-does-magic-find-work-in-guild-wars-2

Comment: @MatthewScharley I didnt think it would give me 100% drop rate. I know that is separate. I did however think that if I had 100% magic drop, it means whenever I do get a drop, it'd be 100% chance non-white text drop.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant to say but I missed a few 'magic's in the second sentence there. Usually these systems work out as I described above; 100% *better* chance to find a magic item as opposed to a normal white item. However, I don't believe there's been any official information that I've seen about how GW2 specifically works.

Comment: @MatthewScharley Oh ok. I see what you are saying. In this case, it might be worth actally getting to the 100% and seeing if i get any white drops at all. If i do then you are probably correct.